# How do I retain the text of any textbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have multiple textboxes with the same class ".input". Each textbox has different default text: First Name, Last Name, etc...

On the focus of a particular textbox, I'd like the default text to go away, and a ".focus" class to be added to the textbox. On the blur of that textbox, I'd like the default text to return if no text has been entered by the user. I'd also like the ".focus" class to be removed unless the user has entered text.

I know how to do this for one textbox, but not multiple (without writing a function for each textbox). I'm guessing there is a way.

I'm also working with asp.NET textboxes so I had to modify the selector.

```
var myText
var myBox
$('input:text.input').focus(function () {
    myText = $(this).val();
    myBox = $(this);
    //alert('focus');
}).blur(function () {
    alert($(myText).val());
});
```

I'm pretty sure the global vars don't retain their values by the time the blur function is called. I've seen this done many times on multiple sites, I just can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I've searched and come up with something close... However, when blur is called, the default text goes away even though I've entered in text.

```
        $('input:text.input').focus(function () {

        if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        }
        if (this.value != this.defaultValue) {
            this.select();
        }
    });
    $('input:text.input').blur(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("focus");
        if ($.trim(this.value == '')) {
            this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help! Here is the code with some tweaks.

```
    $('input:text.input').focus(function () {
       if($(this).hasClass('focus')) { } else {
         $(this)
           .data('stashed-value', $(this).val()) // stash it
           .addClass('focus')
           .val(''); // clear the box
        }
    }).blur(function () {
       if ($(this).val() != '') { } else {
         $(this)
           .val($(this).data('stashed-value')) // retrieve it
           .removeClass('focus');
        }
});
```

Comment: what version of html you are using?

Comment: do you need your HTML to validate? You could add a custom attribute to each text input called `defaultVal` for example, and just use that attribute in your jquery.

Comment: For future proofing, you could supply a value for the placeholder attribute added in HTML5 and use jQuery's attr() function to pull from placeholder and do your processing on it for browsers that don't support HTML5 at the moment.

Comment: Since I'm using asp.NET controls, there isn't a placeholder attribute available. Good thought though!

Comment: Nothing stops you from adding the attribute at design time.  The pages will still compile.  I have added my idea as a possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to stash the value you want to save within the element itself, using [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$('input:text.input').focus(function () {
    $(this)
      .data('stashed-value', $(this).val() ) // stash it
      .val(''); // clear the box
}).blur(function () {
    // presumably you'll check some conditions here (e.g. input empty) then:
    $(this).val( $(this).data('stashed-value') ); // retrieve it
});
```

Comment: +1 for being the only right answer. Unless the OP is building something for internal use, relying on HTML5 is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5, placeholder text will do this for you:

`<input name="q" placeholder="Search Bookmarks and History">`

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#placeholder

You can check it out in Chrome or FF.

You can also do this with jQuery

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Search'){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).val('Search')
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/YaXSg/

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a combination of the answers to create a solution that works in HTML5 compliant browsers and gracefully degrades on others.

Html5:

```
<input type='text' placeholder="First Name" class="input" />
<input type='text' placeholder="Last Name" class="input" />
<input type='text' placeholder="Email" class="input" />
```

jQuery code for backwards compatibility:

```
$('input:text.input').each(function (i) {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))
        {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if (!$(this).val())
        {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
        }
    });
});
```